# SQLite 3 CROSS or INTERSECT complex Subqueries

Tags: sqlite

I have 3 related tables. One table has the rows that I am actually looking for, another table has the Data that I need to be Searching and the Third table describes What data I am looking for.  I am getting undesired results from the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE namesKey IN ( SELECT namesKey FROM data WHERE 
    ( dataType IS 3 AND data IS 'COINCIDENCE' ) 
    AND ( dataType IS 2 AND data IS 'STATE' ) 
    AND ( dataType IS 1 AND data IS 'COUNTRY' ) );
```

I need help making a query based on Multiple rows from the filter table.  I need the rows which correspond to the keys from the second table that exist on multiple rows... I am explaining badly... here is an example :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS names ;
CREATE TABLE names (
    namesKey INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data ;
CREATE TABLE data (
    dataKey INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
    namesKey INTEGER NOT NULL,
    dataType INTEGER NOT NULL,
    data TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(namesKey) REFERENCES names(namesKey)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS filter ;
CREATE TABLE filter (
    filterKey INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
    dataType INTEGER NOT NULL,
    data TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO names( name ) VALUES ( 'name1' );
INSERT INTO names( name ) VALUES ( 'name2' );
INSERT INTO names( name ) VALUES ( 'name3' );
INSERT INTO names( name ) VALUES ( 'name4' );
INSERT INTO names( name ) VALUES ( 'name5' );
INSERT INTO names( name ) VALUES ( 'name6' );
INSERT INTO names( name ) VALUES ( 'name7' );
INSERT INTO names( name ) VALUES ( 'name8' );
INSERT INTO names( name ) VALUES ( 'name9' );

INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 1, 1, 'COUNTRY' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 1, 2, 'STATE' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 1, 3, 'CITY' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 2, 1, 'COUNTRY' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 2, 2, 'STATE' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 2, 3, 'OTHERCITY' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 3, 1, 'COUNTRY' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 3, 2, 'STATE' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 3, 3, 'COINCIDENCE' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 4, 1, 'COUNTRY' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 4, 2, 'OTHERSTATE' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 4, 3, 'COINCIDENCE' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 5, 1, 'OTHERCOUNTRY' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 5, 2, 'RANDOM' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 5, 3, 'COINCIDENCE' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 6, 1, 'OTHERCOUNTRY' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 6, 2, 'OTHERSTATE' );
INSERT INTO data( namesKey, dataType, data ) VALUES ( 6, 3, 'COINCIDENCE' );

INSERT INTO filter( dataType, data ) VALUES ( 1, 'COUNTRY' );
INSERT INTO filter( dataType, data ) VALUES ( 2, 'STATE' );
INSERT INTO filter( dataType, data ) VALUES ( 3, 'COINCIDENCE' );
```

Now what I need is to be able to run 3 different types of queries relatively reliably.

1. I need to search for "No Data" and get names 7, 8, and 9

   - This one is Easy :

     ```
     SELECT * FROM names WHERE namesKey NOT IN ( SELECT namesKey FROM data ) ;
     ```
2. I need to Search based on a Single type of data from the data table

   - Also Easy, Desired Result 3, 4, 5, and 6

     ```
     SELECT * FROM names WHERE 
         namesKey IN ( SELECT namesKey FROM data WHERE 
             ( dataType IS 3 AND data IS 'COINCIDENCE' ) ) 
     ;
     ```
3. I need to Search based on Multiple rows From The filter table.  This one I don't know how to do...

   - Desired Result is the name3 row ONLY
   - I Could do it by

     ```
     SELECT * FROM names WHERE 
         namesKey IN ( SELECT namesKey FROM data WHERE 
             ( dataType IS 3 AND data IS 'COINCIDENCE' ) )
         AND 
         namesKey IN ( SELECT namesKey FROM data WHERE 
             ( dataType IS 2 AND data IS 'STATE' ) )
         AND 
         namesKey IN ( SELECT namesKey FROM data WHERE 
             ( dataType IS 1 AND data IS 'COUNTRY' ) )
     ;
     ```
   - But that is just Ugly with a capital UGH!

And even worse with that approach, the dataType is theoretically arbitrarily large and thus I might end up trying to string together dozens or even Hundreds of sub queries... I could run out of RAM just composing my string before even Trying to put it into the SQL.
So I am looking for a more elegant solution.  Any suggestions?

Comment: ' WHERE ( dataType IS 3 ... )  AND ( dataType IS 2 ...' can never be true since datatype cannot be both 3 and 2  Perhaps you meant OR?

Comment: @ravenspoint Not exactly, and that is problem with the original query.  OR just gives me All the data, results 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6. The Final query in my original post Technically gives me the right data, but that approach has downsides

Comment: If you are getting the correct data, what is the 'downside'

Comment: The biggest one is that I don't know how many different sub-queries I would need to try to cram into a single SELECT.  for this example we are talking about 2 or 3 sub-query terms, that is manageable.  But if I have to put in a separate 'AND namesKey IN ( SELECT namesKey FROM data WHERE (dataType IS %d AND data IS %s ))' every time something new comes up then it balloons out of control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the filter table directly with the actual table to get rows with matches, and then check for only those name keys where all three search terms are matching, i.e., groups whose number of matching rows is the same as the number of all search values:

```
SELECT namesKey
FROM data
JOIN filter USING (dataType, data)
GROUP BY namesKey
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filter);
```

Then use these name keys as usual:

```
SELECT * 
FROM names 
WHERE namesKey IN (SELECT namesKey...);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM names 
WHERE namesKey IN (SELECT namesKey 
                   FROM data 
                   WHERE dataType IS 3 AND data IS 'COINCIDENCE'
                   INTERSECT
                   SELECT namesKey 
                   FROM data 
                   WHERE dataType IS 2 AND data IS 'STATE'
                   INTERSECT
                   SELECT namesKey
                   FROM data
                   WHERE dataType IS 1 AND data IS 'COUNTRY'
                  );
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3a709/3/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════╗
║ namesKey  ║ name  ║
╠═══════════╬═══════╣
║        3  ║ name3 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════╝
```

---

Or using aggregation:

```
SELECT * 
FROM names 
WHERE namesKey IN (SELECT namesKey 
                   FROM data 
                   GROUP BY namesKey
                   HAVING SUM(dataType IS 3 AND data IS 'COINCIDENCE') > 0
                      AND SUM(dataType IS 2 AND data IS 'STATE') > 0
                      AND SUM(dataType IS 1 AND data IS 'COUNTRY') > 0
                  )
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3a709/4/0)**</kbd>